# S3 + CloudFront Distribution -- How to Protect My Assets Folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, serverless

I have a severless website that I am quite happy with. Unfortunately, there are files in my assets folder that I would rather not be served, and I am not sure how to achieve this.

As an example, S3 bucket `mywebsite.com` has several HTML files and an assets folder. If I go to `mywebsite.com/assets/images/image.png` CloudFront serves it up.

This isn't too concerning. But some of the JS stuff with API endpoints, etc should not exposed like this.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Sincerely,
ngp

Comment: Can you provide more details about your S3 buckets (and security configuration)? If the whole S3 is open to public then every file will be accessible to the public.

Please note client-side JS has to be accessible for it to run.

Comment: Code that is needed for your website to run is always available to everyone and the client needs to download it in order to be able to execute it. So there is no way to "hide" the code your website runs from a user. If you can be more specific on your use case or what you want to secure would be helpful to fully understand your problem.

Comment: In serverless or static website everything is expose even API URL. You can't hide this. while calling event its can get from chrome console.

Comment: Thanks everyone.   The S3 bucket is NOT publicly accessible as far as the actual bucket policy.  CloudFront is able to access the bucket.  And it currently serves anything that exists in the bucket.  So, mydomain.com/assets/myjsfile.js exists.  As does mydomain.com/sasets/images/image.png but those resources shouldn't be served as stand alone documents...This would be easy with Apache and a server.  But I am not sure how to achieve this with serverless and CloudFront.  Obviously the client needs to read that data, I just don't want to the URLs to exist and be accessible directly.